# Human and Ultraviolet light

Tags: visible-light, x-rays

As I know, ultraviolet light can be created from burning something at high temperature.

So I have a question: Can a human body become a source of ultraviolet light at high temperature?

If the answer is yes, at what temperature does this happen in a human?

Comment: For the relationship between the temperature and spectrum an object emits, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law

Comment: If you approximate a human as a blackbody, at any temperature it will emmit ultraviolet light.

Comment: I want to know in the real work, Human can emmit ultraviolet light. Do you have some document or paper talk clearly about this.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation.

Comment: As jinawee comments, humans *do* emit in UV at all temperatures, as you'd see if you look at the Planck's law link that Kvothe gives. However, the *dominant* emission for the human body is in IR region. If you want UV to be the *dominant* emission region, then you'll need a body in 10,000 K range.

Comment: Finally, Human body will be burning before it can emmit UV light. It the final answer, right?

Answer (score 4):

Matter in solid, liquid gas or plasma form emits radiation in a spectrum . To a good approximation  this is the [black body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)  spectrum:

[image: black body]

> As the temperature decreases, the peak of the black-body radiation curve moves to lower intensities and longer wavelengths.

From the plot you can see that radiation into the UV is very small even for the 3000Kelvin temperature of the black body. The temperature of red hot iron is about 1000Kelvin so a human body will have burned up way before it can emit any measurable ultraviolet radiation.

Comment: I checked your answer. But as your idea, Human body can't emit Ultra violet, ok? I use Wien's displacement law in your link, for the wave length of ultra violet from 10nm to 400nm.
And I recalculate T, I see just need a very small temperature to emmit ultraviolet. So what wrong in here

Comment: I do not understand. Wien's displacement for 300K ( assumed for the human body) gives 10 microns as the maximum of the shape for a given temperature, way to the right in the first figure, as I said. The temperature for 10nm comes out as 10^6K.